# What does E' (Expression Prime) mean?

Tags: compiler-construction

So, I'm studying Compiler Construction and stucked in this grammar

E->TE'
E->+TE'
and so on....
 My question is What does the E' means actually ?

Answer (score 1):

The `'` does not have any inherent meaning - it's just part of the name. That is `E'` is simply a rule named `E'`.

The usual reason you'd name the rule `E'` instead of just picking a new letter like `F` would be to express that `E` and `E'` are related somehow.

Comment: E doesn't mean any single name in Aho ullmen book i read that it is an Expression but what does mean by E' ?

Comment: @XaadUllah Of course `E` is a name. It's the name of the rule defined by `E -> TE'`. The way that you know it's that production's name is that it's on the left side of the `->`. Similarly `E'` is the name of the rule defined by `E' -> +TE'` (you wrote `E -> +TE'` in your question, but I assume that's a typo because the grammar would make no sense otherwise).

Comment: actually it's so on yeah it is just a typo but i want to know that E means Expression the production rule is like E->TE' which means E(expression) can have a form of term and Expression prime(don't know exactly what does it mean) so if you please elaborate what E' means ?

Comment: @XaadUllah `E` means "A `T` followed by an `E'`" because that's the meaning given to it by the rule `E -> TE'`. Similarly `E'` means "a plus, followed by a `T`, followed by an `E'`". That's all it means. The fact that it stands for "Expression" is merely a naming conventions - it's not part of the syntax and semantics of grammars. If the grammar were written as `A -> TB; B -> +TB`, that would still describe the exact same language.